# I want to pass `id` into index.php without using form but it is not working

Tags: php, html

I want to pass `id` into index.php,my code is as shown below.

my main.php is:

```
<?php 

$rd = dirname(__FILE__); //To Get the Directory Path...
$request[]='';      // To make an empty array

if (empty($request[1]) && empty($request[2]) && isset($_SESSION['l_user']))
{

    $request[1] = 'index';
    $request[2] = '?id=1';
    include_once($rd.'/php_includes/'.$request[1].'.php'.$request[2]); //i think the problem might be here...   
}else {

    $request[1] = 'index';
    $request[2] = '?id=2';
    include_once($rd.'/ph p_includes/'.$request[1].'.php'.$request[2]);  // and might be here
}
?>
```

and my index.php is somethin like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'] == 1)) {
           //Do something...
}else{
           //do something else...
}
```

But it doesn't have any result even it does not have any error.Its not working.

Comment: Enable error_reporting: `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Then you will see your errors.

Comment: You can't pass parameters to an include like that, set `$id` as a variable then it will be accessible within the include.

Comment: Try with [header location](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, You just initilaise the value top of the `include_once`, and you can able to get the initalised variable inside the included file (i.e index.php). Note that you can't able to pass the value as query string in include ad require

```
$id = '1';
include_once($rd.'/php_includes/'.$request[1].'.php');
```

in index.php

```
 if($id=="1"){

  }else{

  }
```

Comment: I didn't know that i can't able to pass a value as query string in include and requre.that was very informative,it Works now thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `header` instead of `require_once` because `require_once` is like `include` it copy the included code in the file.

```
<?php 

$rd = "http://ip_address"; // ip_address or dns name
$request[]='';      // To make an empty array

if (empty($request[1]) && empty($request[2]) && isset($_SESSION['l_user']))
{

    $request[1] = 'index';
    $request[2] = '?id=1';
    header('Location:'.$rd.'/php_includes/'.$request[1].'.php'.$request[2]); //i think the problem might be here...   
}else {

    $request[1] = 'index';
    $request[2] = '?id=2';
    header('Location:'.$rd.'/php_includes/'.$request[1].'.php'.$request[2]);  // and might be here
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this sample code, or the actual one? Because it's unusual to use array to pass the same URL instead of passing the whole string

```
include_once($rd.'/php_includes/index.php?id=1');
```

your code might be turned into this

```
<?php
$rd = dirname(__FILE__); //To Get the Directory Path...
# it seems that the session is important :)
if (isset($_SESSION['l_user']))
{
    $id=1; 
}else {
    $id=2;
}
include_once($rd.'/ph p_includes/index.php?id='.$id);
?>
```

Comment: dude i can't able to pass the value as query string in include_once so it wont work

Comment: Well, then delete this
`?id='.$id`
 piece of code and inside index.php check 
`if $id===1 
{
#session isset
} else { 
#session is not set
}`